# Load xml files in SQL according to their names(name has date, include only last six month)

Tags: sql, xml

I have xml files in a folder and periodically new xml files are being added to this folder. First time I need just to load all files to SQL. That I can do.  But later I need to keep all my files and load(or reload if needed) files for the last six month(If I have a three month old file, I have to reload it). Indication of the date is in the name of the files(e.g. 123_01032023_456.xml). If I just need to load files, I'm using xp_dirtree. But what can I do in this case? Thank you very much in advance!
This is my code that I have now.

```
 Truncate Table [1].[PG_FileList] 
    Insert into files EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree 'E:\123\Load_Test',1,1; INSERT INTO [PG_FileList]
          ([FilePath],
           [DBFilePath] ,
           [FileName] ,
           [DateLoaded]) 


select 
       '\\1\Load_Test' FilePath ,
       'E:\1\PG_Load_Test' DBFilePath ,
       Subdirectory as FileName 
      ,Getdate() [DateLoaded] from files 
    where [FILE] = 1
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Standard SQL has no loading.)

Comment: @jarlh I'm using 
Truncate Table [1].[PG_FileList]
Insert into files EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree 'E:\123\Load_Test',1,1;

INSERT INTO [PG_FileList]
           ([FilePath]
           ,[DBFilePath]
           ,[FileName]
           ,[DateLoaded])
select 
'\\1\Load_Test' FilePath
,'E:\1\PG_Load_Test' DBFilePath
,Subdirectory as FileName 
,Getdate() [DateLoaded]

from files
where [FILE] = 1

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Your comment also doesn’t show which DBMS you are using. Please tag your question with the correct DBMS e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc

Comment: @NickW SQL. I'm sorry, I put it in the title and I've edited my question

Comment: What is your RDBMS and its version?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky SQL server management studio v.18.1.1

Comment: It is just the IDE, we need RDBMS and its version. Please issue `SELECT @@VERSION;` and share it here.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)

Comment: What is your exact question: (1) How to retrieve a **date part** from the XML file names, or (2) How to shred XML files and load into database table(s)?

Comment: I think I've figured out how to retrieve date. Main question how to load last 6 month files(add them to old files). Instead of rewriting everything, I need to keep old files and rewrite files for the last 6 month.

Comment: It is better to use SSIS for your task

Comment: Thank you @YitzhakKhabinsky.  But I have to use SQL Server. If possible could you please help me to figure out how to do it with SQL Server?

Comment: SSIS is a part of SQL Server. It stands for SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS).

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I understand, sorry, I didn't express my self correctly. I need to write a store procedure that can accomplish this task.

Comment: You need to post a new question as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): (1) Source XML file sample., (2) Target SQL Server table `CREATE ... ` T-SQL statement, (3) Your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.